# Bootstrap modal keep disappearing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying to display a modal after i click a button. The problem is the modal pops up but then it closes back automatically. I have linked only two js files which are bootstrap.js and jquery.js in the head section.

This is my head section:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

This is the code for the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat ="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopupBookForm"/>
```

And this is the modal:

```
 <div class="modal" id="PopupBookForm" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Event Form</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Meeting Title :"></asp:Label><br />
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="meetTitle" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                         <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Date of Meeting :"></asp:Label><br />
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="meetDate" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Meeting Start :"></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="meetStart" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Meeting End :"></asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="meetEnd" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Plant :"></asp:Label>
                                    <select ID="plantDropDown"  class="form-control" style="width:200px">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Plant</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Room :"></asp:Label>
                                    <select id="roomDropDown" class="form-control"  style="width:200px">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Room</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Meeting Description :"></asp:Label><br />
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="meetDesc" class="form-control" runat="server" Textmode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Employee ID :"></asp:Label><br />
                            <asp:TextBox type="text" ID="empID" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnPopupCancel" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Cancel"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnPopupSave" CssClass="btn btn-outline-success" runat="server" Text="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Much Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Webforms generates custom HTML for its controls based on the control type and might override javascript events like onclick ...

You should not use ASP controls unless you need to access them in the backend.

Try using a simple html element:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopupBookForm">
     Launch demo modal
</button>
```